# Python: Method X instances class A and calls method E. When this class is instanced it calls method X again. How to solve it in a good way?

Tags: python, oop

Well, the whole problem is described in the question title. As you guys can see, I have this problem when making the calls.

BTW, consider that I am already importing all the needed libs and classes.

Check my code below:

```
class PyUtility(object):

    #@Arguments:
        #path = file path to be opened 
        #op = mode in which the file will be opened, r+ by default
    #Return: A file for writing or reading, depending on the value of op variable
    def loadPath(self, path, op='r+'):
        print 'loadPath()'
        try:
            #In case the path string is '/example/example', instead of 'example/example'
            if path[0] == '/':
                path = path.lstrip('/')
            return open(path, op)
        except Exception, e:
            print 'A new file has been created!'
            directories = path.split("/")
            #In case the path string is '/example/example', instead of 'example/example'
            if directories[0] == '':
                directories.pop(0)
            #Retrieving the file to be loaded, it is the last one in the list
            fileName = directories.pop()
            newPath = ''
            #In case the file is to be created in the root folder there will be no iteration, therefore frk will be empty
            frk = ''
            for directory in directories:
                frk = '/'
                #Browsing through the directories and creating them if necessary
                newPath = newPath + directory
                if not os.path.exists(newPath):
                    os.makedirs(newPath)
                newPath = newPath + frk
            newPath = newPath + frk + fileName
            #Here it lies the problem... The method X (loadPath) will instance class A (Log) and call method E (error)
            Log().error(e)
            return open(newPath, 'w')


class Log(object):

    #Opens all log files and loads the current number of lines for each
    def __init__(self):

        errors_path = "logs/"+strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())+"/errors_log.txt"
        #Now that the class is being instanced it calls method X (loadPath) again
        self.errors_log = PyUtility().loadPath(errors_path)
        self.errors_log.seek(0,2)

    def error(self, e):
        self.errors_log.write("Error ["+str(self.errors_count)+"] @ "+strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S", gmtime())+": "+str(e)+"\n")
        self.errors_count = self.errors_count + 1
```

My partial solution doesn't please me, I created another "loadPath" method inside of Log class, I just named it as "loadLog" and it works fine. But I wonder if there is any other alternative.

Cheers []'

Comment: When `Log` calls `loadPath`, does that path already exist (I'm assuming it does) or is there a possibility it'll go through the `except` block of `loadPath`. Obviously, the latter situation would be cyclic!

Comment: Well, that is the key of the problem. When it does not exist already, It goes through the except block of loadPath and goes cyclic, what I am asking is for a better way to solve it, maybe with nested classes, I don't know, any other way that does relate with the creation of another method that is the same. It is one of the Ten Commandments: Thou shall never write the same method twice. So it is probably because I think I might be the case that I am commiting a mistake due to lack of knowledge or experience (even though I try to go with good practices ;) ).

Comment: A few comments unrelated to the issue you're having: The `PyUtilty` class is pretty useless, you should make `loadPath` just a normal function. You should almost never catch all exceptions with `except Exception`, but instead only the error or errors you're going to be able to deal with (in this case, you probably want to catch `FileNotFoundError` and nothing else). Lastly, your `loop` over the directories in your path is unnecessary, since `os.makedirs` will already create all the necessary directories if you just give it the leaf directory. Try `os.mkdirs(os.path.dirname(path))`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the whole PyUtility class (it has all the methods that I've been using for more than once), loadPath is just another one of them. It is great class for using in other projects. 

Regarding catching Exception, going for FileNotFoundError doesn't buy me anything more than Exception, they will end up the same and it gives me the chance to catch other unexpected errors. (such as protected file or stuff like that)

And for the loop, I do not want to create a dir called "file.txt"

Comment: Also, regarding the loop, I may eventually want to have the chance to create a 'a2' in case dir 'a' already exists. It is just not there ,but if I ever feel the need, it will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple solution.

Personally, I like to keep methods rather short. I'm not saying you have to adhere to my personal tastes for this to work, but there is in my opinion a very easy way to do away with problems like this. Whenever a function starts becoming big like `def loadPath()` (and I know some will say that's small), there's a good chance you can refactor it nicely. My definition of ***big*** is when the ratio of implementation details to intent is too high. In other words, I tend to err on the side of [declarative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).

#### So what now?

Simple. Just refactor it.

```
import os

class PyUtility(object):

    def loadPath(self, path, op='r+'):
        print 'loadPath()'
        try:
            return open(path.lstrip('/'), op)
        except Exception, e:
            Log().error(e)
            return open(createvalidpath(path), 'w')

def createvalidpath(path):

    directories = path.split("/")
    #In case the path string is '/example/example', instead of 'example/example'
    if directories[0] == '':
        directories.pop(0)
    #Retrieving the file to be loaded, it is the last one in the list
    fileName = directories.pop()
    newPath = ''
    #In case the file is to be created in the root folder there will be no iteration, therefore frk will be empty
    frk = ''
    for directory in directories:
        frk = '/'
        #Browsing through the directories and creating them if necessary
        newPath = newPath + directory
        if not os.path.exists(newPath):
            os.makedirs(newPath)
        newPath = newPath + frk

    return newPath + frk + fileName
```

---

```
class Log(object):

    #Opens all log files and loads the current number of lines for each
    def __init__(self):

        errors_path = "logs/"+strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())+"/errors_log.txt"

        self.errors_log = (
            open(errors_path, 'w') if os.path.isfile(errors_path) 
            else open(createvalidpath(errors_path), 'w')
        )
        self.errors_log.seek(0,2)

    def error(self, e):
        self.errors_log.write("Error ["+str(self.errors_count)+"] @ "+strftime("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S", gmtime())+": "+str(e)+"\n")
        self.errors_count = self.errors_count + 1
```

You see, `createvalidpath` is now just a module-level function (and why not?). There's nothing that says functions must all be part of a class. After all, it seems like it might get called from many different places. If eventually you end up with a related group of functions that perform filepath operations and if it makes sense that they should share state, create a new `class` and go from there.

#### Avoiding cyclic call

As you can see, `Log` can call `createvalidpath` safely *if it needs to*. It's only `loadPath` that needs to log an error, not `createvalidpath`. So, in essence, both functions perform one concrete action, intention, etc. Think of it this way when you're writing a long function: *Is there a good chance that buried in this function I may have to re-use part of it separately?* If yes, refactor it.

By the way, this bit was unnecessary...

```
if path[0] == '/':
    path = path.lstrip('/')
```

I changed it to:

```
return open(path.lstrip('/'), op)
```

Because ultimately if there isn't a `'/'` in front, it'll return the result as is. The up-side is you get to simplify the code a bit more.

Comment: Oh, this last part was unnecessary as well,  I do realize that. But thanks for your attention and hints on code refactoring. 

Still, I get the following error: 

  File "/home/ricardo/Documentos/IC/web-crawler/Log.py", line 9, in __init__
    pU = PyUtility()
NameError: global name 'PyUtility' is not defined

Comment: You know, I think I will go with your recomendation and create another class just to manage files. Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoSilveira This `NameError: global name 'PyUtility' is not defined ` seems to be unrelated to your question though. And, to be honest, it's a bit vague. There are countless potential reasons you might be getting a `NameError`. It could be getting called before it's been defined, or isn't being called from the right module, etc.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira If the answer was to your satisfaction, don't forget the green tick ;) ... And if it's not I'll glady improve it where the question is concerned.

Comment: Eithos, this NameError is related to the cyclical nature of the problem. It happens when you call somebody who has already been called before and so on to a certain level taht I don't even know how to explain. I created a PyGhostWriter class and now it works just fine. And I didn't know about the green tick, thanks for the reminder. I am really new here, I usually ask labmates for help, but it is carnival season in Brazil and I do not want to stop this project. But yeah, thanks for the advice!